# Resolve services in app.run, bad logic?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I discovered an issue with doing service calls in the .run method. Seems like the controllers doesn't wait for the services to resolve before moving on

```
.run(['User', 'Translation', function(User, Translation) ... service injection
```

Get the user:

```
$rootScope.user = User.get();
```

Get translation based on the users preferred language

```
$rootScope.user.$promise.then(function(user) {
    $rootScope.translation = Translation.language(user.user_language.toLowerCase()).then(function(translation) {
        $rootScope.translation = translation.data;
    });

    Do Intercom and other stuff...
});
```

In the controller we set some property on an object to a translation like

```
$scope.obj = { prop: $scope.translation.prop }
```

This fails 10% of the times, i'm guessing, due to the fact that the language services hasn't been resolved yet.

All initialization of stuff like Intercom, Segment.io are based on information about the user, so thats we also tried to get the language resolved in .run

The question is what should i do instead. Seems repetive to resolve the services on every state (ui-router) in the application.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create an abstract route as a root state for all your app and resolve that route with the wide-app data. If that causes you a lot of trouble refactoring then you may want to check John Papa course.

I remember him mentioning a solution in his last course:

[angularjs-patterns-clean-code](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/angularjs-patterns-clean-code)

You can use Pluralsight trial period to consume most of the course for free. Sorry about not remembering the solution right now.

Comment: Please post it here if you find out :)

Comment: John Papa doesn't put this logic into .run because it make it more difficult to test, he says. So it didn't solve my problem. The user object is fetched and ready before any additional resolves on the various states, is one might expect. The problem is the nested call to translation (a $http call).The controllers doesn't wait for it to resolve and I can't understand why...

Comment: Here's what i found of option: bootstrap the app manually and do some logic beforehand, add a resolve on every state, extend the .config with a function that injects the resolve on every state and create an abstract state.I think your suggestion of creating a abstract state and resolve global dependencies there is the best solution on this matter! Sry, havent got a reputation to upvote you :D

Comment: You can put a function in the app.run, but the key is to defer it to a service/factory that you use injection with. That way you can test it with mocks and stubs.

Comment: regarding adding a resolve to every state, check out my sample solutions on github. they offer a routehelper (or statehelper) that provides an easy way to add a resolve on every route (for things like loading data or auth)